# How to create an SVG animation from a single common input file that is also used by others?

Tags: animations, animate, dvisvgm

I have a single input file as follows.

```
% input.tex
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=25+25,\r=2.5+2.5}{144}{%
\pspicture[algebraic,plotpoints=\i,linecolor=red](-2.1,-2.1)(2.1,2.1)
\parametricplot{0}{\r}{2*sin(7*t*Pi/180)|2*cos(11*t*Pi/180)}
\endpspicture}
\end{document}
```

I want this input file to be reusable everywhere.

> Write once, reuse everywhere!

### Case 1 (imported as a still image)

If we compile `input.tex` (compilation: `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`) to produce a multipage PDF, the last page can be imported from within another input file (compilation: `pdflatex`) with `\includegraphics[page=144]{input.pdf}`.

### Case 2 (imported to create a PDF animation)

If we compile `input.tex` (compilation: `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`) to produce a multipage PDF, the PDF can be imported from within another input file (compilation: `pdflatex`) with `\animategraphics[...]{...}{input.pdf}{}{}` to get a PDF animation.

### Case 3 (converted to create a GIF animation)

If we compile `input.tex` (compilation: `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`) to produce a multipage PDF, the PDF can be converted by ImageMagick to get a GIF animation.

### Case 4 (converted to create a series of PNG or JPEG images)

If we compile `input.tex` (compilation: `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`) to produce a multipage PDF, the PDF can be converted by ImageMagick to get a series of PNG or JPEG images.

### Case 5 (converted to create a series of SVG images)

If we compile `input.tex` (compilation: `latex-dvisvgm`) to produce a series of SVG images.

## Questions

How to create an SVG animation with control panels (play, pause, forward, backward, etc) from the same `input.tex`? I call it as the 6th case and the last case is to create an SVG animation without control panels.

Constraint: I don't want to modify the `input.tex` by sandwiching with `\animateinline` directly.

Comment: Though possible, what is the purpose of producing series of SVG?

Comment: I am asking, because creating an animated SVG (as requested in the title) from a series of SVG leaves the SVG files of the series external. (They must be shipped together with the main SVG.) It is better to create the animated SVG from a series of PS files. They will be converted to inline SVG code, making the animated SVG self-contained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input.tex` can be used as is, for all cases, to first produce DVI

```
latex input
```

### Further processing:

---

### cases 1 to 4 and 6 (multipage PDF)

```
dvips input
ps2pdf input.ps output.pdf
```

### case 5 (series of numbered SVG)

```
dvisvgm --exact --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 -p1,- --output=output-%p.svg input
    
# on windows
dvisvgm --exact --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 -p1,- --output=output-%%p.svg input
```

### case 6 (animated SVG from multipage PDF)

File `master.tex` for producing the animated SVG from all pages in `output.pdf`:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[dvisvgm]{animate}
\usepackage[dvisvgm]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\animategraphics[controls]{12}{output}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Compile to animated SVG with

```
latex master
dvisvgm --exact --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 master
```

Comment: We will have to wait for TexLive-2019 to embed from multipage PDF using `dvisvgm`.

Comment: @Artificial . I uploaded a new version of `animate`, 2019/01/23, to CTAN. It allows inclusion of multipage PDF but requires a recent `dvisvgm`. Thus, for case 6, instead of `pdf2ps ..`, simply run `ps2pdf input.ps`, and leave framenumbers empty in `\animategraphics`, to embed all pages in `input.pdf`. Tested with MikTeX.

Comment: Maybe it is not a bug, and precision below 3 is just too imprecise for visually good output?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Yes, the outputs are visually indentical (internally, object translations are different, but scaling is identical. So are the SVG paths converted from PDF input). I updated **(6)** to use existing multipage PDF instead of series of PS files.

Comment: `dvisvgm` crops to the visual content by default, with option `--exact` up to glyph outlines with high precision, if these happen to make up the bounding box. If you want to keep the paper dimensions, add `--bbox=papersize`.

Comment: Nice! Thank you!